# Could you help me with drawing house with turtle graphics?

Tags: python, graphics, 2d, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I can not understand how to properly draw a house in python with turtle. I've tried several ways, but house is always with incorrect lines that are going somewhere else. Can you help and draw little house with doors and and window? I have exam about this drawing.

```
# veido majas pirmo stavu
k.fillcolor('cyan')
k.begin_fill()
k.right(90)

k.forward(250)
k.left(90)
k.forward(400)
k.left(90)

k.forward(250)
k.left(90)
k.forward(400)
k.right(90)

k.end_fill()
# veido majas jumtu
k.fillcolor('brown')
k.begin_fill()

k.right(45)
k.forward(200)
k.right(90)
k.forward(200)

k.left(180)
k.forward(200)
k.right(135)
k.forward(259)

k.right(90)
k.forward(142)
k.end_fill()
# for door and

# windows
y.right(90)
y.forward(400)

y.left(90)
y.forward(50)
y.left(90)

y.forward(150)
y.right(90)
y.forward(200)
y.right(90)

y.forward(150)
y.right(90)
y.forward(100)
y.right(90)

y.forward(150)
y.right(90)
y.forward(100)
y.right(90)

y.forward(75)
y.right(90)
y.forward(200)
y.right(180)

y.forward(200)
y.right(90)
y.forward(75)
y.left(90)

y.forward(15)
y.left(90)
y.forward(200)
y.right(90)

y.forward(15)
y.right(90)
y.forward(75)
```

Comment: if it helps i could show code

Comment: Try `turtle.drawHouse()` :) Jokes aside, you need to share at least the relevant part of the code otherwise no one can be able to help you.

Comment: k.fillcolor('cyan')
    k.begin_fill()
    k.right(90)
    k.forward(250)
    k.left(90)
    k.forward(400)
    k.left(90)
    k.forward(250)

Comment: Please edit your initial question and add the code there.

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the house consists of a triangle and a square. So just google it or stackoverflow it how to draw square and triangle with the turtle, and then try to link them (2 shapes) together. Hope this helps! If not, read the documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html) and learn how to properly move a turtle. Before drawing anything, try to imagine the house shapes (where to turn left, right or maybe 45 degrees) and figure how long you want each side to be.

Note: It is better to not copy any code from the Internet, do your best and draw it by yourself using the documentation. This way you'll improve your turtle drawing skills and abstract imagination :)

Comment: well, big thanks for your response, but thing is that, its my last class in IT, and i do not see my self in future programming codes, so i just need to make it work

Comment: Oh okay, then just try to google it, but thanks to python syntax its turtle is not a big deal to get used to it. It would take no more than 10 minutes to find and read the part of documentation you need. Anyways, good luck!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are not very familiar with pyhton, I made a little program on the fly that does just that for you, you can try to modify it and study the turtle documentation to make it do what you want, meanwhile it has a good starting point :)

```py
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()

# for background
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.bgcolor("white")

#color and speed
# of turtle
t.color("black")
t.shape("turtle")
t.speed(10)

# base of the house
t.fillcolor('grey')
t.begin_fill()
t.right(90)
t.forward(250)
t.left(90)
t.forward(400)
t.left(90)
t.forward(250)
t.left(90)
t.forward(400)
t.right(90)
t.end_fill()

# for top of
# the house
t.fillcolor('red')
t.begin_fill()
t.right(45)
t.forward(282)
t.right(90)
t.forward(282)
t.right(45)
t.end_fill()


# windows
t.right(90)
t.forward(400)
t.left(90)
t.forward(50)
t.left(90)
t.forward(150)
t.right(90)
t.forward(200)
t.right(180)
t.forward(200)

t.fillcolor('white')
t.begin_fill()
t.right(90)
t.forward(200)
t.right(90)
t.forward(150)
t.right(90)
t.forward(200)
t.right(90)
t.forward(150)
t.right(90)
t.forward(100)
t.end_fill()

t.right(90)
t.forward(150)
t.right(90)
t.forward(100)
t.right(90)
t.forward(75)
t.right(90)
t.forward(200)
t.right(180)
t.forward(200)


# for door

t.right(90)
t.forward(75)
t.left(90)
t.forward(15)
t.left(90)
t.forward(200)
t.right(90)
t.forward(15)
t.right(90)
t.forward(75)
t.fillcolor('brown')
t.begin_fill()
t.circle(10)
t.end_fill()
t.forward(120)
```

[image: house]

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```py
from turtle import *
# veido majas pirmo stavu
k = Turtle()
k.speed(10)
k.penup()
k.goto(-200,0)
k.pendown()
k.fillcolor('cyan')
k.begin_fill()
k.right(90)

k.forward(250)
k.left(90)
k.forward(400)
k.left(90)

k.forward(250)
k.left(90)
k.forward(400)
k.right(90)

k.end_fill()
# veido majas jumtu
k.fillcolor('brown')
k.begin_fill()

k.right(45)
k.forward(200)
k.right(90)
k.forward(200)
k.end_fill()
k.color('#205375')
k.begin_fill()
k.left(180)
k.forward(200)
k.right(135)
k.forward(259)

k.right(90)
k.forward(142)
k.setheading(180)
k.forward(120)
k.end_fill()
k.hideturtle()


# windows
y = Turtle()
y.speed(10)
y.penup()
y.goto(-200,200)

y.right(90)
y.forward(400)

y.left(90)
y.forward(50)
y.pendown()

y.left(90)

y.forward(150)
y.right(90)
y.forward(200)
y.right(90)

y.forward(150)
y.right(90)
y.forward(100)
y.right(90)

y.forward(150)
y.right(90)
y.forward(100)
y.right(90)

y.forward(75)
y.right(90)
y.forward(200)
y.right(180)

y.forward(200)
y.right(90)
y.forward(75)
y.left(90)
y.backward(200)
y.hideturtle()


z = Turtle()

z.penup()
z.speed(10)
z.goto(-90,40)
z.pendown()
z.forward(50)
z.setheading(90)
z.forward(50)
z.setheading(180)
z.forward(50)
z.setheading(270)
z.forward(50)
z.setheading(0)
z.forward(25)
z.setheading(90)
z.forward(50)
z.setheading(180)
z.forward(25)
z.setheading(270)
z.forward(25)
z.setheading(0)
z.forward(50)
z.hideturtle()


s =Screen()

s.listen()
def func(e,t):
    print(e,t)
s.onclick(func,btn=1)

x = Turtle()
x.speed(10)
x.penup()
x.goto(110,140)
x.begin_fill()
x.fillcolor('#205375')
x.setheading(90)
x.forward(50)
x.setheading(0)
x.forward(20)
x.setheading(270)
x.forward(50)
x.end_fill()
x.hideturtle()

done()
```